# Regular expression of a formal language with a number of a's equal to a multiple of 7 and a number of b's not equal to a multiple of 5?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-expressions

\begin{equation}
    L_{26} = \{w\ |\ |w|_a \equiv 0 \text{ (mod 7)} \wedge |w|_b \not\equiv 0 \text{ (mod 5)}, w \in \{a, b\}^*\}
\end{equation}

The language is defined as above, how would one go about designing a regular expression for this? I'm also not to sure how to start, as I'm very new to formal languages and regex. The pieces puzzling me the most are the requirement for a certain amount of a's or b's.

Comment: You say "and" in the title of your question and $\lor$ in the body. Which did you mean? Depending on the answer, your language is either the intersection or the union of two languages that might be regular. Does that help?

Comment: @RobArthan ∨ is and is it not

Comment: No. $\lor$ means "or" and $\land$ means "and". (One clue is in the $\LaTeX$ names: \lor and \land).

Comment: PS: you are getting downvotes (not from me) because you have said nothing about what you have tried. What have you tried?